# Creating thumbnail images in markdown Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, markdown, gatsby

I am following [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-images-in-markdown/) tutorial to create thumbnails for a list of articles on my gatsby site. I have successfully created "featured" images in my src/templates/blog-post.js with the following code

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

export default ({ data }) => {
  const post = data.markdownRemark
  let featuredImgFluid = post.frontmatter.featuredImage.childImageSharp.fluid
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <h1>{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
        <h2>{post.frontmatter.author}</h2>
        <Img fluid={featuredImgFluid} />
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
        author
        featuredImage {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 800) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

I wanted to move these "featured" images to my index.js so I could have a table of contents with post title, author name, date, and excerpt and so did the following in src/pages/index.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

export default ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <h1>
          Amazing Pandas Eating Things
        </h1>
        <h4>{data.allMarkdownRemark.totalCount} Posts</h4>
        {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => (
          <div key={node.id}>
            <Link to={node.fields.slug}>
              <h3>
                {node.frontmatter.title}{" "}by{" "}{node.frontmatter.author}{" "}
                <span>
                  — {node.frontmatter.date}
                </span>
              </h3>
              <Img fluid={node.frontmatter.featuredImage.childImageSharp.fluid} />
              <p>{node.excerpt}</p>
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

//, limit: 6

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allMarkdownRemark(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          id
          frontmatter {
            title
            author
            date(formatString: "DD MMMM, YYYY")
            featuredImage {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 800) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                }
              }
            }
          }
          fields {
            slug
          }
          excerpt
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

but I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of null. What am I
>   doing wrong?

My [Github](https://github.com/develijahlee/yonseiuicscribe)

Comment: you need a `featuredImage` field in the frontmatter of *all* of the markdown files you are querying, otherwise you can't query `childImageSharp` of something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Really? Because `featuredImage` works on my blog-post.js even though I included 3 images out of the 166 posts I have.

Comment: It might work on a blog post with a `featuredImage`. What happens if you go to a blog post without `featuredImage` in the frontmatter?

Comment: the post shows up with plain text without the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I needed a `featuredImage` field in the frontmatter of all of the markdown files I was querying. All 166...